# SQL Query and case statement to show multiple entries by joining two tables

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2012

Here is an example of two tables and I would like to create a view as end result. There are two tables as input to the view, one that has countries with location id and the other has location names, I want to join them and then do a case to replace multiple counts with single entry.
Any help is appreciated.

[Here is the screenshot of how tables look like, Table Entity and Table Location as input tables to the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/li1OI.png)

I first thought of getting counts of multiple location Id from Entity Table and then create a select Case statement but no avail, here is the draft code.

```
select
    Country, count(locationid),
    case LocationName
        when Cnt > 1 then 'Mulitple offices'
        when Cnt = 0 then 'Unknown Location'
        else LocationName
    end
from 
    Entity 
group by 
    Country
```

UPDATE:
I just made a [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/da9a0/2) (pretty handy) and realized both solutions from @Gordon and @P.Eh but with some issues. See specific in comments below

Comment: Case _expression_, not _statement_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this is what you wanted:

- when *location_id* in **location** table is *NULL* or *0* then 'Unknow location'

```
select
    COU.Country,
    case 
        when COU.pleace is null OR COU.pleace=0 then 'Unknow location'
        when COU.number_of_pleaces > 1 then 'Multiple offices'
        else coalesce(LOC.Location_name,'cound not math location')
    end as [location name]
from
    (   select country,
            sum(1) as number_of_pleaces,
            max(Location_id) as pleace
        from @entity
        group by country
    ) COU
    left join
    @location LOC
        on LOC.Location_id = COU.pleace
        and COU.number_of_pleaces = 1
```

Comment: Thanks @P.ejH, I am trying this code, the code: 'max(location_id) as Pleace throws multi-part identifier couldnt be found!, any help is appreciated

Comment: Tested again in SQLFiddle (see the link above in question), especially for UK it throws Multiple Offices which is wrong. otherwise work fine. Can we tweek a bit to write 'Unkown Location' if the location_id is zero

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want something like this:

```
select e.Country, count(l.locationId),
       (case when count(l.locationId) > 1 Then 'Mulitple offices'
             when count(l.locationId) = 0  then 'Unknown Location'
             else max(l.LocationName)
        end)
from Entity e left join
     Location l
     on e.locationId = l.locationId
group by e.Country;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your response, I think that's pretty close. the query returns multiple offices where it finds count > 2 but for other cases its all NULL. Dont know whats the issue. any guess

Comment: I am not that worried about 'Case e.locationID = 0' but why it doesnt get the max(l.locationName) ?

Comment: @Abdul . . . Perhaps no countries have only one location.

Comment: I tried the modified code, its throws all zeros, i guess because the location table doesnt really have multiple records to count. BTW, I have records that shows a country has only one location

Comment: Why cant I remove Max(l.LocationName) and use just L.locationname, so I get the actual value, do I need to end the each case first?

Comment: @Abdul . . . Because you have an aggregation query and doing that would generate an error.

Comment: Interestingly, your solution works fine in SQLFiddle (see the link above in question) but not in my local environment, it throws all NULL except for Multiple Offices, the only difference in my environment is the Location table is in different database, its pretty wierd

Comment: If table 'Location' is in different database, then you have to point to it:
so instead 'location' use 'otherdatabasename.dbo.location'